# Failed to start chromium on a X-forwarded ssh connection

Tags: ssh, chrome, xterm, xforwarding

When I tried to start chromium, I had error messages :

```
$ chromium
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
[10139:10139:0321/173002.675673:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(234)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[10139:10139:0321/173002.675976:ERROR:env.cc(225)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0

$ xterm # xterm starts fine
```

Comment: Hello. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I faced the same issue but still found problems. I will let you know if I will find out the proper solution for that.

Comment: @RaulChiarella I have not found a solution.

Comment: Oh. Ok... Thank you. @Philippe

Answer (score 0):

check

```
env | grep DISPLAY
```

and match running the command

```
DISPLAY=:1 chromium
```

Comment: `env | grep DISPLAY` gives `localhost:10.0`. I don't have X-Server on ssh server, so `DISPLAY=:1` wouldn't work.